# Protecting my php includes from mailicious users

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, include

I have been reading on how to protect my .php includes. The main suggested option is to place the .php files I want to protect outside the folder that serves the .php files which is /public_html in my case.

So, I decided to make a folder named /includes and I access my .php includes from the /public_html .php files like ../includes/file.php. This works nicely but I am being a bit paranoid.

Can I go ahead and add an .htaccess with the following line on /includes:

```
Deny from all
```

I know the user is not supposed to access the /includes in my case. Though, would that .htaccess file in /includes hurt me in any case?

Thank you.

Comment: `.htaccess` files  are read by the web server, so it will do nothing outside the web root

Comment: Better ask yourself if your system is vulnerable, how easy for another user is to tamper with your code, why your includes only and not all your system.

Answer (score 0):

A really good way is to have a front controller (FC) manage all of your resource requests, and htaccess to route everything to the FC.

Then if someone tries to access something on your site it'll be routed through FC. It will in turn call a router which should only allow loading of files this way which are in a specific directory.

So attempting to navigate to (eg) `includes/someScript.php` wont work because FC wont route a web request into the includes dir.

This won't affect your requiring them within PHP files as this request wont go through the FC.